# Gesture detection in Expanded Container

Tags: flutter, gesture

I have an area of my widget that is created with an expanded container like:

```
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
      child: Text(
        startTime,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: TextStyle(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        /* If this gesture detector is instantiated the tap is never found;
        child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () => print("OnTap"),
        */
        child:
          Container(color: Colors.red[600]),
        //),
      ),  // Expanded
  ], // children
), // Column
```

If the above code is wrapped with this

```
Expanded(
  child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onTap: () => print("OnTap"),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red[600],
      child: // Code above
    ), // Container
  ), //GestureDetector  
), // Expanded
```

Then the onTap is only registered in the text widget, but never in the last expanded container.

Is it correct that the detection does not trigger on the Container and needs a widget to fill the space to be detected?

**Edit**
I changed the gesture detection for the expanded container to be:

```
Expanded(
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.red[600],
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {print("InkWell");},
    ),  // InkWell
  ),  // Material
),  // Expanded
```

And the tap is still not recognized.

Comment: Can you show the parent widget of Column ? and code starting from body , if you're using scaffold ?

Comment: @Anas Mohammed I solved the problem by rewriting the Future Builder, returns a SpannableGrid instance, to be more concise.  Am I supposed to delete the question or add my own answer? The code is several hundred lines of code and no one will learn anything from it other then I started flutter two weeks ago?

Comment: Its up to you. You can write up a solution describing why it was not working or if you think writing answer will not help anyone then you can delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet of code should work fine, I think your getting an error from another part of your code, can you provide the full code please? And also what you're getting in the console.

This is your code snippet fully working in DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/f76d383475c5c7c35ca4bf59b0a83789

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it is being added to the SpanaableGridView, and I have no idea what they are doing.

Comment: Are you talking about this SannableGrid: https://pub.dev/packages/spannable_grid? It will be helpfull if you provide all the code of your page. If you think the issue is link to the package I suggest you to open an issue here: https://github.com/ech89899/spannablegrid-flutter/issues

Comment: The page is over 350 lines long and makes calls to proprietary api's to get then info to display.  I will write a smaller page and fake the data to make it understandable.  Is there no other way to debug flutter apps?

Comment: Since your error is from UI we can't help you if you're not providing details about your ui, to debug you use your console log, if there is an error preventing Flutter to build properly the UI it will be here. Otherwise it's never a good thing to combine UI code and calls to the API if you want your code to stay clear and understandable.

Comment: I appreciate your help, The page can't be displayed without the data from the api, I use a future builder, to build the ui so there are many places it can go wrong.  I have been using flutter for maybe 2 weeks now so by far would I consider myself anything other then a novice.  I am having trouble with the future builder now.  It's like pushing a rope uphill.