# How do I make my widget clickable in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

So I tried to implement **Gesture Detector** but i gives me this error, can anyone help me with that?

```
FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight.
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED))
```

so here i have my code, where i just added the gesture detector and then it started givin me this error, when i remove the gesture detector code the app runs perfectly well, it only fails when i try to implement that as clickable widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_card_pager/vertical_card_pager.dart';
import 'models/hero_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //List for agents and respective gif for each one.
  final List<HeroModel> heros = [
    HeroModel("JETT", "images/jett_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("KILLJOY", "images/killjoy_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SAGE", "images/sage_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SOVA", "images/sova_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("VIPER", "images/viper_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("RAZE", "images/raze_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("YORU", "images/yoru_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("BREACH", "images/breach_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("ASTRA", "images/astra_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("CYPHER", "images/cypher_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("OMEN", "images/omen_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("PHOENIX", "images/phoenix_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SKYE", "images/skye_valo.gif"),
  ];

  @override
  //Head Logo
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 70,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/logo.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // CardView
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Expanded(
                child: VerticalCardPager(
              titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
              images: [
                for (var hero in heros)
                  Hero(
                    tag: hero.title,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        hero.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              initialPage: 2,
              align: ALIGN.CENTER,
            )))
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

an this is my class code.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class HeroModel {
  late String title;
  late String image;

  HeroModel(this.title, this.image);
}
```

Comment: expanded is only used directly on the children of a column or row.  in your code, your Gesture detector wrap all children  VerticalCardPager.
try to switch the parent widget

Comment: can you show any example?

Comment: i just putted the gesture detector inside the expanded as a child and it worked, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to put `GestureDetector()`

inside:

```
              Expanded(
                child: VerticalCardPager(
              titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
              images: [
                for (var hero in heros)
                  Hero(
                    tag: hero.title,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        hero.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),....
```

[edit] just like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){},
    child: VerticalCardPager()
    ), 
  ), 
)
```

Comment: you mean inside the expanded?

Comment: yes, look at the edit above

Comment: you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542414/gesture-detection-in-expanded-container as reference, cmiiw

Comment: alright, happy coding